# How to display or insert new layout between two layouts which are already there?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am trying to create a dynamic simple table which takes income and expenditure and sum them up. My layout is like:

First Line : Total Income ----------

Second Line: Total Expenditure ------

What I want is, when I click on First line (I have done it as linear layout), a table layout will display just below the first line, which includes the subtitles of income. It means, the table layout will need to push the Second line below it.

I tried doing

```
 tablelayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and making it visible by onclicklistener with first line.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tablelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

But, the problem is, even if setting invisible, the tablelayout still occupy the space between first and second line, which doesnt look normal. 
I tried adding the tablelayout using the onclicklistener -

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mainlayout.addView(tablelayout);
        }
    });
```

Now, in this case, table layout is displayed below the second line, not right under the first line.
Any suggestions please.

Comment: use view.Gone inplace of Invisible

Comment: When somebody Down vote the question, why not give a reason on comment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just use like this Because INVISIBLE method just hide your view only So You will try to give GONE method

```
 tablelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It will give to you what you are expecting...

Answer (score 3):

Try with-

```
tablelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and make it visible on onClick() as you are doing

> View.INVISIBLE - means This view is invisible, but it still takes up
>   space for layout purposes.
>
> View.GONE  -  This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space
>   for layout purposes.

Comment: Got it. GONE was the word I was looking for.